# How to send a https request using jetty

Tags: https, request, client, embedded-jetty

This is my client setup

```
    SslContextFactory sslContextFactory = new SslContextFactory();
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePath("keystore");
    sslContextFactory.setKeyStorePassword("blah");
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(sslContextFactory);
```

and this is my how I get the request object.

```
        Request request = client.newRequest(host, port);
```

How do I send the request as https?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is

request.scheme(HttpScheme.HTTPS.toString()):

that is all